# How to find the inverse metric in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, linearized-theory

Caroll, while proving the Newtonian limit takes $$g_{ab} = \eta_{ab} + h_{ab}$$

He then just writes down the inverse metric to 1st order as $$g^{ab} = \eta^{ab} - h^{ab}$$

I don't see how this calculation has been done. It looks like some kind of  Binomial theorem has been used but I don't see how.

Can anyone help me with the steps in between and what the inverse metric will look like to 2nd or 3rd order in $h$?

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183487/

Comment: I assume you know how to show that the expression given there is in fact the inverse to first order? I.e. show that the metric with its inverse gives the identity.
It doesn't make sense to find the inverse to higher order in *h* if the metric is only defined to first order in *h*.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/446667/2451 and links therein.

Comment: \begin{equation}
\left(1\boldsymbol{+}x\right)^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\stackrel{\vert x\vert\boldsymbol{<\!\!<}1}{\boldsymbol{\approx\!\approx\!\approx}} 1\boldsymbol{-}x
\tag{a}\label{a} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}\boldsymbol{=}\eta_{\mu\nu}\left(1\boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{h_{\mu\nu}}{\eta_{\mu\nu}}\right)\quad \boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow} \quad \cdots\cdots
\tag{b}\label{b}  
\end{equation}

Comment: @Frobenius, When I first encountered the problem of inverting a metric tensor, I solved it for myself in the way that I've shown in the edit (I'm not good at writing formulas in comments).

Comment: @SG8 : You post a good answer I upvoted one hour before my comment. The latter I post since the OP talks about the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: @Frobenius, Thanks ... I know :) ... I just wanted to share my old way with you :) As you know, there are much better ways than mine.

Answer (score 3):

The Newtonian limit is defined as

$${g_{\mu \nu }} = {\eta _{\mu \nu }} + {h_{\mu \nu }},\,{\rm{where}}\,\,\,\left| {{h_{\mu \nu }}} \right| <  < 1.$$

From the definition of the inverse metric, i.e. ${g_{\mu \lambda }}{g^{\lambda \nu }} = \delta _\mu ^\nu $, one can check that ${g^{\mu \nu }} = {\eta ^{\mu \nu }} - {h^{\mu \nu }}$ is the inverse up to first order in $h$, i.e.

$$\begin{array}{l}
{g_{\mu \lambda }}{g^{\lambda \nu }} = ({\eta _{\mu \lambda }} + {h_{\mu \lambda }})({\eta ^{\lambda \nu }} - {h^{\lambda \nu }})\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = {\eta _{\mu \lambda }}{\eta ^{\lambda \nu }}\underbrace { - {\eta _{\mu \lambda }}{h^{\lambda \nu }} + {h_{\mu \lambda }}{\eta ^{\lambda \nu }}}_{ = 0} - {h_{\mu \lambda }}{h^{\lambda \nu }}\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \delta _\mu ^\nu \, - O({h^2}).
\end{array}$$

*An edit motivated by the Frobenius's comment:*

When I first encountered the problem of inverting a metric tensor, I solved it for myself in this way:

$$\begin{array}{l}
{g_{\mu \lambda }}{g^{\lambda \nu }} = \delta _\mu ^\nu \, \Rightarrow \,{g^{\lambda \nu }} = \frac{{\delta _\mu ^\nu }}{{{g_{\mu \lambda }}}}\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \frac{{\delta _\mu ^\nu }}{{{\eta _{\mu \lambda }} + {h_{\mu \lambda }}}}\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \delta _\mu ^\nu ({\eta ^{\mu \lambda }} - {h^{\mu \lambda }})\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = {\eta ^{\lambda \nu  }} - {h^{\lambda \nu  }},
\end{array}$$

where ${(1 + x)^{ - 1}} \approx 1 - x$ has been used in the third line. My essential rule (which, I admit, is a slightly awkward thing to do) was this: In expansions, every (tensor) quantity that goes from the denominator to the nominator, its indices also go up and down accordingly.